# Firefox Addon Attach event for PageMod is not emitting events

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am unable to communicate between my addon and my attach script.  The attach event for PageMod works however it doesn't emit my `getElements` event to my list-getter.  How do you use the `port.emit` method properly?  Thanks!

index.js (addon)

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.workflowy.com",
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.11.3.min.js"), data.url("list-getter.js")], 
  onAttach: function(worker) {

    // For some reasong the worker doesn't emit?
    worker.port.emit("getElements");

    worker.port.on("gotElements", function(times) {
      function printValues(el) {
        console.log(el);
      }
      times.forEach(printValues);
    });
  }
});
```

list-getter.js (contentScriptFile)

```
self.port.on("getElements", function() {
  var timeRegex = /\bam|pm/g
  var openLists = $('.project.open').find('.content');
  var times = []
  for (var i = 0; i < openLists.length; i++) {
    if (openLists[i].innerHTML.match(timeRegex)) {
      times.push(openLists[i].innerHTML)
    }
  }
  self.port.emit("gotElements", times);
});
```

Comment: Communication is all right. Change `openLists` to let's say `$('div').find('div')` and you'll see. You must have some other problem, concerning your regex or - more likely - using wrong selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I made an incredible blunder.  Make sure to put anything that you want loaded by the data object inside of the data folder.  I had two copies and was changing the wrong one.  Thanks.

index.js

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.workflowy.com",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("list-getter.js"), 
  onAttach: function(worker) {

    worker.port.emit("getElements");

    worker.port.on("gotElement", function(times) {

      function printValues(el) {
        console.log(el);
      }
      times.forEach(printValues);
    });
  }
});
```

list-getter.js

```
self.port.on("getElements", function(openProject) {
  var times = []
  var timeRegex = /\b([1-9]pm|[1-9]am|1[0-2]am|1[0-2]pm)/g;
  var openLists = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  for (var i = 0; i < openLists.length; i++) {
    if (openLists[i].innerHTML != "") {
      if (openLists[i].innerHTML.match(timeRegex)) {
        times.push(openLists[i].innerHTML);
      }
    }
  }
  self.port.emit("gotElement", times);
)};
```